# Github branch name pattern

Tags: github

can i restrict barnch name in our pattern so all developers can follow predefined format of branch name?
I want to apply branch name pattern globally so when developer create branch and submit code , then branch name must first validate with our defined naming convention, if succeeded then it will pass to remote other show error message in local system

Thanks

Comment: no clue if this is possible. You might just want to tell them the correct convention and save yourself some trouble

Comment: You can utilize git hooks for it, please review husky npm project and how it is implemented there. Git hooks could be setup on client side or backend side

Comment: can you share me url of husky ? @KrzysztofSafjanowski

Comment: I checked in gitlab, push rules are mentioned in settings, but seems no setting in github repository

Comment: I can't use .git/hooks otherwise i need to update every developer individually, it's manual work, i'm looking for global process

Comment: What stack are you using? You can prepare install script that will fetch git repository and will introduce local git hooks. Even if you bootstrap project for local development you can add method that have access to local environment and will modify hooks.

Comment: I'm uisng react js ( frontend ) and want to use git hooks @KrzysztofSafjanowski